# Query Oracle DB for timestamps when you know milliseconds

Tags: database, oracle, timestamp

I'm currently getting the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

which I assume is to do with the way I am setting a timestamp...

So I have a query like this :

```
select * from A_TABLE where A_TIMESTAMP_COL < '1252944840000'
```

But it doesn't work...and I don't want to have to convert it to a date ideally. Is there some special syntax to tell Oracle that this is a timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can cast the date column to a char and do something like:

```
select * from A_TABLE where to_char(A_TIMESTAMP_COL) < '1252944840000'
```

This should allow you to compare strings, not dates.

Comment: This seems like a very bad idea to me.  I believe Oracle will have to run that function on every value it compares rather being able to do the comparison natively.  I'd like to see performance for both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the to_timestamp() function to convert your string into a timestamp value: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions201.htm#sthref2458

Answer (score 0):

Use the `java.sql` convenience methods to take that milisecond time and turn it into a Date or Timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM A_TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP < (SYSDATE - 10/1440)
```

Where `(SYSDATE - 10/1440)` means `SYSDATE - 10 Minutes`.

Also see some examples [here](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_add_a_day_hour_minute_second_to_a_date_value).